# How to assign a variable to an if statement in a for loop?

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to have my **for loop and if statement** in **a line**.

Expanded Code:

```py
for  item in number:
    if item['datetime'] not in number:
        print('Not there')
```

I tried this:

```py
eg = [if item['datetime'] not in number: print('Not there') for item in number]
```

Code:

```py
                    req = requests.get(url2 + str(page))
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
                    g_data = soup1.find_all('span', {"class": "b-card b-card-mod-hvehicle"})
                    g_price = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b-card--el-vehicle-price"})
                    g_mile = soup.find_all('p', {"class": "b-card--el-brief-details"})
                    g_name = soup.find_all('p', {"class": "b-card--el-description"})
                    g_user = soup.find_all('a', {"class": "b-card--el-agency-title"})
                    g_link = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b-card--el-inner-wrapper"})
                    g_sales = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "b-card--el-featured-label"})
                    time = soup.find_all('time', {"class":"timeago b-card--el-agency-time"}) 
                    m_price = [item.text for item in g_price]
                    m_mile = [item.text for item in g_mile]
                    m_user = [item.text for item in g_user]
                    m_name = [item.text for item in g_name]
                    m_link = [item.a["href"] for item in g_link]
                    m_extensions = [('') for item in g_link]
                    m_sales = [item.text for item in g_sales]
                    r_time = [dateutil.parser.parse(item['datetime']).strftime('%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S') for item in time]
                    req2 = requests.get(m_extension + m_link)
                    soup_req2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.content, 'html.parser')
                    number = soup_req2.find_all('a',{"class": "b-seller--el-show-contacts b-line-mod-thin"})
                    test1 = (if item['mobile'] not in item: item = ('Sold') for item in number)
```

Gives me a syntax error.
Thanks!

Comment: don't use list comprehensions for side-effects, but the comprehension works like `[expression for x in iterable if predicate]`, but again, you shouldn't use that here. A list comprehension is not a "one-line for loop", it is a functional programming construct to express mapping/filtering operations on iterables to produce a list

Comment: Can you give the expanded code?

Comment: *Why* would you like to have your `for` loop and `if` statement in one line? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am scraping data from a website which has multiple pages.

Comment: @Tvnyl I'm trying to follow your code logic...... is number a dictionary and item is a dictionary too? Then you're indexing into item that indexes into number? What? Give us some more info to work with

Comment: The code you gave will print the line `"not there"` `len(number)` times. What was your actual plan?

Comment: I will edit the post with more info.

Comment: You *could* just remove the line breaks and put your original code simply on one line. But why, do you have a shortage of lines?

Comment: I've added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has a contradiction --> `item in number` but you also have `item['datetime'] not in number`

I'll try put an example:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

To make list of even numbers:

```
evenNo = [x for x in numbers if x%2==0]
```

Similar to above, but just print the even numbers instead of putting a list:

```
printEven = [print(x) for x in numbers if x%2==0]
```